Simulating Engine Breakdowns in R
Here is my R code for 5 engine failures in parallel: all engines start with a failure probability of 0.5...each turn the probability of failure increases by 0.01 ... when it fails for the first time, its out forever. This continues until all 5 engines have failed:
    engines <- paste0("engine_", 1:5)  
prob_working <- 0.5

max_turns <- 100  

df <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = 11, nrow = max_turns))
colnames(df) <- c("turn", paste0("engine_", 1:5), paste0("engine_", 1:5, "_prob"))

for (i in seq_along(.engines)) {
    engine <- .engines[i]
    turn <- 1
    while(turn <= max_turns) {
        result <- ifelse(runif(1) < prob_working, "working", "failure")
        
        df[turn, "turn"] <- turn
        df[turn, engine] <- result
        df[turn, paste0(engine, "_prob")] <- prob_working
        
        if (result == "failure") {
            break
        }
        
        prob_working <- prob_working - 0.01
        
        prob_working <- max(prob_working, 0)
        
        turn <- turn + 1
    }
    

    if (df[turn, engine] == "failure") {
        prob_working <- 0.5
    }
}


df <- df[1:max(df$turn, na.rm = TRUE), ]
df

See below:
 turn engine_1 engine_2 engine_3 engine_4 engine_5 engine_1_prob engine_2_prob engine_3_prob engine_4_prob engine_5_prob
1    1  failure  failure  working  failure  working           0.5           0.5          0.50           0.5          0.50
2    2     <NA>     <NA>  failure     <NA>  working            NA            NA          0.49            NA          0.49
3    3     <NA>     <NA>     <NA>     <NA>  working            NA            NA            NA            NA          0.48
4    4     <NA>     <NA>     <NA>     <NA>  failure            NA            NA            NA            NA          0.47

How can I change this code so that at the start of each turn, we look at how many engines have failed ... and the remaining engines from now on will have a failure probability of 0.01 * (n+1) , where n = number of failed engines?

As was suggested yesterday, if the failure of each engine depends on the number of other non-operational engines, you will need you outer loop to manage time and your inner loop to manage engines.

I am trying to do this and keep running into problems...

"I ... keep running into problems": then you need to be more specific.

Should I post it? thanks!

For this simulation, we can avoid loops altogether by pre-calculating the probability that an engine fails on each turn. The probability of failing on turn 1 is 0.5. The probability of failing on turn 2 is the probability of surviving turn 1 and failing on turn 2 (0.5*0.51). The probability of failing on turn 3 is the probability of surviving turns 1 and 2 and failing on turn 3 (0.5*0.49*0.52), etc., all the way up to turn 50, which has a 100% probability of failure. Once we have that, we can get the cumulative distribution function of failure turn and simulate as many engines as we want using findInterval:
(seed <- sample(.Machine$integer.max, 1))
#> [1] 979709928
set.seed(seed)
# probability of failure for each turn given that it was running at the
# beginning of the turn
p <- seq(0.5, 1, 0.01)
# cumulative failure probability
p <- cumsum(cumprod(c(1, 1 - p[-length(p)]))*p)
# Run the simulation once for 5 engines. On what turn do each fail?
findInterval(runif(5), c(0, p))
#> [1] 2 3 1 5 3
# perform 1M replications of the 5-engine simulation
system.time(res1 <- matrix(findInterval(runif(5e6), c(0, p)), 1e6, 5))
#>    user  system elapsed 
#>    0.14    0.00    0.15


A vectorized approach that does not require pre-computing the CDF:
p <- 0.5 # initial probability of failure
N <- 5e6L # number of engines to simulate
n <- integer(50) # initialize the number of failed engines for each turn
i <- 0 # initialize the current turn

system.time({
  while (N) {
    i <- i + 1 # increment the turn
    n[i] <- rbinom(1, N, p) # how many engines failed this turn?
    N <- N - n[i] # how many engines are still running?
    p <- p + 0.01 # increment the failure probability
  }
  # put the results into a matrix--each row is a 5-engine simulation 
  res2 <- matrix(sample(rep(1:i, n[1:i])), 1e6, 5)
})
#>    user  system elapsed 
#>    0.60    0.00    0.59

Compare the results of the two simulations.
mx <- max(res1, res2)
cbind(res1 = tabulate(res1, mx), res2 = tabulate(res2, mx))
#>          res1    res2
#>  [1,] 2497594 2499018
#>  [2,] 1276645 1276342
#>  [3,]  637211  636379
#>  [4,]  312041  311886
#>  [5,]  149921  149492
#>  [6,]   69770   69668
#>  [7,]   31846   32085
#>  [8,]   14313   14318
#>  [9,]    6181    6247
#> [10,]    2647    2674
#> [11,]    1097    1133
#> [12,]     452     479
#> [13,]     171     176
#> [14,]      82      55
#> [15,]      21      31
#> [16,]       6      13
#> [17,]       1       3
#> [18,]       1       0
#> [19,]       0       1


@ jbloog94: thank you for this mathematical approach! is it possible to do this from a non-mathematical way? e.g. just using the simulation steps i described?

See the update for a vectorized approach that does not require the CDF.
